# Unity3d Google Play Games Services process reward data? C#

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

Does anyone know how i would do this:
[Code mentioned at https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzkJO.png)

for C# in Unity3d. I am trying to put quests into my android app, but am having problems understanding how.
Specifically, i need to insert a reward data file into the developer console, and somehow add the value of coins scored in that to player prefs. I really have no clue how.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Reward data is specific to your application. I suggest using the [plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) to incorporate google play games. You can store the reward data and type as a json and associate it with the quest (see [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/quests#specifying_reward_data)). To modify PlayerPrefs, read the reward data from the quest, and then just call the [class](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) to set values (from reward data) and save it once you're done.

Comment: I have the plugin installed, but i really can't get my head around the json data file. Can you walk me through? Basically what i need to know is the last part, which is how to read the reward data. Thanks @Andy

Comment: You can call [getComplettionRewardData](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/quest/Milestone.html#getCompletionRewardData()) in the event that the quest has been completed. You can probably use something similar to their [sample](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/samples/TrivialQuest/Source/Assets/TrivialQuest/TrivialQuest.cs#L136-L151) and call getCompletionRewardData on the milestone you get.

Comment: But the reward data is a byte. How do i turn this into say an int. Sorry to be such a pain, but im only 14 and am really stuck. Thanks again @Andy